# Flex 4.5 Mobile - How to deploy and access images / data

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, filesystems

I am working on a Flex 4.5 app tageting Android. In different views the app needs to load and display images which I have deployed as part of the app.

Where do I put these images? And how do I load them?

I am familiar with @Embed for images, but this doesn't seem to be the correct approach in this case. I also know how to load from the file system, but I really don't know how to include my images as part of the app for distribution.

Thanks if you can help.

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in a mobile app that I wrote in Flex:

I have the following files:

```
src/assets/images/myImage.png
src/myApp.mxml
```

Inside `myApp.mxml` I have an image that references the one in the assets:

```
<s:Image source="../assets/images/myImage.png" />
```

I have NO idea why I have to go up one directory to make this work as the `assets` folder is in the same folder as the MXML file... but this is what worked for me.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have to add the images as assets compiled into the final app? Or does that happen automatically?  I thought if the images weren't embedded they weren't included as part of the distribution unless you explicitly tell the app to to do so.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Indeed, you need to compile those assest into the final app.  But that happens by default.  You'd have to opt out of including the images using this method.

Comment: I had no idea it did it by default using this approach.  Good to know; thanks!